# A Javascript Filter button, help completing it?

Tags: javascript, html, json, button, filter

```
filterbutton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   let three = Drink.allDrinks.filter(drink =>{
     if (drink.ingredients.length < 3)
      return true
   })
```

This is my Javascript code i need help with above, I know that im almost finished with it but I am missing something. I would gladly appreciate some assisstance on how to finish this function so that my filter button which is supposed to filter the results with 3 or more ingredients.

Below is my html for the button

```
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Filter" id="filterbutton">
```

Comment: check your brackets/parens

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code, you may have to adapt it a bit but still :)

```
filterbutton.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    let data = data.filter(drink => drink.ingredients.length>3)
})
```

I used codepen to test it if you wanna check :
https://codepen.io/LENNY74/pen/xxRVLxQ

Comment: index.js:44 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'fil' before initialization
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (index.js:44)